# Dynamic HTTP URI with recipientList returns 404 on the second call

Tags: apache-camel

I have two step camel route workflow - both steps make POST call to the same host, but the URL and body is different. The first call returns part of the URL for the second call.

Here is the code:

```
// I register converter for different request types
getContext().getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverters(new RequestConverter());

from("direct:two-step-flow")
  .setHeader("paramId", body().method("getParamId")
  .setHeader("url", "http://localhost:8080/api/${header.paramId}
  .convertBodyTo(Step1Request.class)
  .to("direct:call-remote-service")
  .convertBodyTo(Step2Request.class) // converter sets newParamFromResponse
  .setHeader("url", "http://localhost:8080/api/${header.paramId}/${body.newParamFromResponse}
  .to("direct:call-remote-service")
.end();

from("direct:call-remote-service")
  .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
  .recipientList(header("url"))
  .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, GenericResponse.class)
.end();
```

First step works fine, HTTP flow is something like

```
httpclient.wire.header - >> "POST /api/p1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" 
httpclient.wire.content - >> "{"amount":1.22,"reason":"some reason","relation-id":"12345"}"
httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.header - << "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer - Http responseCode: 200
```

Second step fails with HTTP 404

```
httpclient.wire.header - >> "POST /api/p1/Id1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - >> "{"action":"CONFIRM","reason":"reason to confirm","relation-id":"12345"}"

org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer - Http responseCode: 404
httpclient.wire.content - << "<html>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<head>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<title>Error 404 </title>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "</head>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<body>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<p>Problem accessing /api/p1/Id1. Reason:[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org   /jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.11.v20160721</a><hr/>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "</body>[\n]"
httpclient.wire.content - << "</html>[\n]"
```

The same POST works with curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/p1/Id1' -i -X POST -H
'Accept:application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d
'{                                 
    "action" : "CONFIRM",
    "relation-id" : "12345",
    "reason" : "reason to confirm"
 }'
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)
```

I might be misusing .recipentList, any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its some HTTP response headers that are picked up and used for the 2nd call. Therefore try removing the HTTP headers between the 2 calls: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html

Add

```
.removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
```

Before you call the route with the recipient list

```
.to("direct:call-remote-service")
```

Comment: Did not help. I've added the response for the 1st call in the question.